# Silverlight 4 Email AutomationFactory.CreateObject throws exception

Tags: silverlight-4.0, outlook

I am trying to launch Outlook from a Silverlight 4 application. I referred this [article](http://elegantcode.com/2010/02/20/silverlight-4-com-interop-and-the-cool-stuff-you-can-do-with-it/). But the code throws exception as "This operation is not supported in the current context."

Please suggest what needs to be done to fix this issue?

```
using (dynamic outlook = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Outlook.Application")) 
{
    dynamic mail = outlook.CreateItem(0);
    mail.To = ""; 
    mail.Subject = "Hello, from Silverlight";
    mail.HTMLBody = "";
    mail.Display(); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Is your application running Out of Browser?  Is it running as a Trusted Application (you checked the "Require elevated trust" checkbox in the OOB settings window)?  Is this code running on Windows?

`AutomationFactory` is only usable of all three answers above are "yes".  To verify that everything is as it should be, you should check that `AutomationFactory.IsAvailable` is true before calling any other `AutomationFactory` APIs.  This has the bonus that your code can easily detect when that functionality will not be available to either warn the user, fall back to other behavior, or not show the option in the UI at all.

Also, to verify the hopefully-obvious: does the machine this is running on have Outlook installed?

Comment: Austin, I have done all the settings you mentioned... Is there any requirement with user permissions? or some other browser settings?

Comment: Does `AutomationFactory.IsAvailable` return true and yet still this exception is thrown?